# html fire function from external javascript file and return cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm trying to set up a login-system. For now I just care about the look, so I use cookies to save accounts and show the names and so on.

I create and read my cookies in an external javascript file, but for some reason I can't fire the event to read the cookie and display the name when the page loads.

I tried both

```
window.onload = CheckCookie();
```

and
    $(document).ready(CheckCookie);

The second method fires the main function without any problems, but there's no reaction when firing the `CheckCookie()` function (which is a child of the main function).

So I want to fire the event from the html part, but I have no clue how to access the cookie. I use some functions to get the correct cookie without having to split everything.

How can I fire that event as soon as the page loads?

Comment: You should definitely post some more code. And for the record, `document.cookie` is available anytime in the web browser.

Comment: This was a general question, so i didn´t thought it was necessary to add the code. I´ll think about that next time. I know that document.cookie is available anytime, but i got a function which returns the value of a cookie with a given name instead of returning one string with all cookies. That was the problem, but i fixed it with Hitmands answer and minor tweaking on my side.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want do something on page load, you have to do something like that:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ReadCookieCtrl);
function ReadCookieCtrl() {
  var self = this;

  self.getCookie = function() { return document.cookie; }
  self.setCookie = function(value) { document.cookie = value; }

  console.log('Cookie', self.getCookie()); //Just invocation
}
```

Comment: Down-voting should allegate some comment!

Comment: Nice, it worked for me! Idk why you got a downvote, but it was not mine.